# Query works fine as stand alone but gives an error when used in a function

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, union

I have this simple query working fine (my actual query is much more complex than this, I just created this one as an example):

```
select mc_id, mc_referencia
from movcuentas1
where tm_id = 1 and mc_concepto = 'Amort Int'
UNION 
select mc_id, mc_referencia
from movcuentas2
where tm_id = 2 and mc_concepto = 'Amort Capital'
order by mc_referencia
```

BUT when I try to use it within a function such as this:

```
USE [dozfin]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SampleF] (@mes as integer, @anio as integer)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
select mc_id, mc_referencia
from movcuentas
where tm_id = 1 and mc_concepto = 'Amort Int'
UNION 
select mc_id, mc_referencia
from movcuentas
where tm_id = 2 and mc_concepto = 'Amort Capital'
order by mc_referencia
)
```

When tring to save, it gives me this error: "Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SampleF, Line 15
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified."

Any ideas?

Comment: You should really use `ORDER BY` when using your function, not inside of it: `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SampleF](1,2017) ORDER BY mc_referencia` or something like that

Comment: Putting an order by in your function is rather pointless. It does not mean that any query that uses this will return in that order. If you want to order results it MUST be in the final query. There are no work arounds for this.

Comment: You're right about that, only that I don't have acces to the source code to modify the final query. i'm looking for a workaround. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Message error is clear, add a TOP clause to the sentence with ORDER BY.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SampleF] (@mes as integer, @anio as integer)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    select mc_id, mc_referencia
    from movcuentas
    where tm_id = 1 and mc_concepto = 'Amort Int'
    UNION 
    select top 100 percent mc_id, mc_referencia
    from movcuentas
    where tm_id = 2 and mc_concepto = 'Amort Capital'
    order by mc_referencia
)
```

**Just a sample**

> ```
> create table foo (id int identity, val int);
> insert into foo values (1),(2),(3),(4);
> ```

> ```
> create function dbo.test(@id int)
> returns table
> as
> return
>     select id, val from foo where id = @id
>     union
>     select top 100 percent id, val from foo where id > 3 order by val desc;
>
> GO
> ```

> ```
> select * from dbo.test(2);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  2 |   2
>  4 |   4
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=794a2356c2a123b1796337e7f57c1c93)*

Comment: What is the point of adding `ORDER BY` in a function? Hacking with `TOP 100` doesnt make sense.